# Segmenting a Bezier curve into equal lengths in tikz/pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-core

I'm trying to draw two curves and then create equal sized segments/arcs using pgf/tikz but for some reason the segments are not equally sized. I want to go on and fill each segment with a different color using radial shading. I would have thought this is a standard thing to do and am surprised at how difficult it appears to be. Maybe I'm going about it the wrong way? I have also tried using an ellipse with arcs but again the segment sizes get smaller at the poles.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\tikzstyle{help lines}=[blue!20, very thin];
\draw[help lines, step=1mm, very thin] (-10,-10) grid (10,10)
 [help lines, step=1cm, thin] (-10,-10) grid (10,10);


\pgfmoveto{\pgfpointxy{-1.3}{0}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpointxy{-3.3}{-5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{-.3}{-5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{0}{-5.3}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpointxy{.3}{-5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{3.3}{-5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{1.3}{0}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpointxy{3.3}{5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{.3}{5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{0}{5.3}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpointxy{-.3}{5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{-3.3}{5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{-1.3}{0}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.5}
\pgfusepath{stroke}

\pgfmoveto{\pgfpointxy{-1}{0}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpointxy{-3}{-5}}{\pgfpointxy{-.1}{-5}}{\pgfpointxy{0}{-5}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpointxy{.1}{-5}}{\pgfpointxy{3}{-5}}{\pgfpointxy{1}{0}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpointxy{3}{5}}{\pgfpointxy{.1}{5}}{\pgfpointxy{0}{5}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpointxy{-.1}{5}}{\pgfpointxy{-3}{5}}{\pgfpointxy{-1}{0}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.5}
\pgfusepath{stroke}

\foreach \y [remember=\y as \x (initially 0)] in {.1,.2,...,1} {
  \pgfpathcurvebetweentime{\x}{\y}{\pgfpointxy{-1.3}{0}}{\pgfpointxy{-3.3}{-5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{-.3}{-5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{0}{-5.3}}
 \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointcurveattime{\y}{\pgfpointxy{-1}{0}}{\pgfpointxy{-3}{-5}}{\pgfpointxy{-.1}{-5}}{\pgfpointxy{0}{-5}}}
 \pgfpathcurvebetweentimecontinue{\y}{\x}{\pgfpointxy{-1}{0}}{\pgfpointxy{-3}{-5}}{\pgfpointxy{-.1}{-5}}{\pgfpointxy{0}{-5}}
 \pgfpathclose
 \pgfsetstrokeopacity{1}
 \pgfusepath{stroke}
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! What is 'srcs'?

Comment: Misspelt. Should read arcs.

Comment: Thank you - I was quite mystified. (I didn't think of a typo - for some reason, I tried to make it an abbreviation but couldn't think of what.)

Comment: Bezier curves are not parametrised by arc length.  One way to achieve this would be to use a decoration that marks the curve at suitable intervals with coordinates (then afterwards join those coordinates).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a suggestion using a decoration to mark points along the curves and then loop through joining them up.  I'm using TikZ-level commands for the decoration which jars slightly with the low-level PGF commands that you're using; but I don't know the low-level equivalents off the top of my head.

It works because decorations step along paths according to path length, not parametrisation (which doesn't work since a Bézier is not guaranteed to be parametrised by path length).  Since there is already a decoration that marks a curve at intervals, the simplest implementation is to use that decoration on each curve and then afterwards join them up.

(If you used TikZ commands for drawing the actual curves, you could combine the whole draw-and-mark bit for the curves into a single draw command with suitable choices of post-action.)

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/242016/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\tikzstyle{help lines}=[blue!20, very thin];
\draw[help lines, step=1mm, very thin] (-10,-10) grid (10,10)
 [help lines, step=1cm, thin] (-10,-10) grid (10,10);


\pgfmoveto{\pgfpointxy{-1.3}{0}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpointxy{-3.3}{-5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{-.3}{-5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{0}{-5.3}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpointxy{.3}{-5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{3.3}{-5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{1.3}{0}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpointxy{3.3}{5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{.3}{5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{0}{5.3}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpointxy{-.3}{5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{-3.3}{5.3}}{\pgfpointxy{-1.3}{0}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.5}
\pgfusepath{stroke}

\pgfmoveto{\pgfpointxy{-1}{0}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpointxy{-3}{-5}}{\pgfpointxy{-.1}{-5}}{\pgfpointxy{0}{-5}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpointxy{.1}{-5}}{\pgfpointxy{3}{-5}}{\pgfpointxy{1}{0}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpointxy{3}{5}}{\pgfpointxy{.1}{5}}{\pgfpointxy{0}{5}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpointxy{-.1}{5}}{\pgfpointxy{-3}{5}}{\pgfpointxy{-1}{0}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.5}
\pgfusepath{stroke}

 \def\coordk{0}
 \draw[
   decorate,
   decoration={
     markings,
     mark=between positions 0 and 1 step .1 with
     {
       \coordinate (outer-\coordk) at (0,0);
       \pgfextra{\pgfmathtruncatemacro\coordk{\coordk+1}
       \global\let\coordk=\coordk}
     }
   }
 ]
 (-1.3,0) .. controls (-3.3,-5.3) and (-.3,-5.3) .. (0,-5.3);
\def\coordk{0}
 \draw[
   decorate,
   decoration={
     markings,
     mark=between positions 0 and 1 step .1 with
     {
       \coordinate (inner-\coordk) at (0,0);
       \pgfextra{\pgfmathtruncatemacro\coordk{\coordk+1}
       \global\let\coordk=\coordk}
     }
   }
 ]
 (-1,0) .. controls (-3,-5) and (-.1,-5) .. (0,-5);

 \foreach \y in {0,...,9} {
   \draw (outer-\y) -- (inner-\y);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Marked curves]

Note that due to inherent inaccuracies in the marking algorithm, it sometimes doesn't mark the final point which is why I only iterated over the coordinates up to the 9th.  However, the final line segment is easy to put in place so that isn't a serious concern.

---

*Edit* Here's a version using TikZ-level code for everything.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/242016/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{help lines}=[blue!20, very thin];
\draw[help lines, step=1mm, very thin] (-10,-10) grid (10,10)
 [help lines, step=1cm, thin] (-10,-10) grid (10,10);

 \def\coordk{0}
 \draw[
   postaction={
     decorate,
   },
   decoration={
     markings,
     mark=between positions 0 and 1 step .025 with
     {
       \coordinate (outer-\coordk) at (0,0);
       \pgfextra{\pgfmathtruncatemacro\coordk{\coordk+1}
       \global\let\coordk=\coordk}
     }
   }
 ]
 (-1.3,0)
 .. controls (-3.3,-5.3) and (-.3,-5.3) .. (0,-5.3)
 .. controls (.3,-5.3) and (3.3,-5.3) .. (1.3,0)
 .. controls (3.3,5.3) and (.3,5.3) .. (0,5.3)
 .. controls (-.3,5.3) and (-3.3,5.3) .. (-1.3,0);

 \def\coordk{0}
 \draw[
   postaction={
     decorate,
   },
   decoration={
     markings,
     mark=between positions 0 and 1 step .025 with
     {
       \coordinate (inner-\coordk) at (0,0);
       \pgfextra{\pgfmathtruncatemacro\coordk{\coordk+1}
       \global\let\coordk=\coordk}
     }
   },
   opacity=.5
 ]
 (-1,0)
 .. controls (-3,-5) and (-.1,-5) .. (0,-5)
 .. controls (.1,-5) and (3,-5) .. (1,0)
 .. controls (3,5) and (.1,5) .. (0,5)
 .. controls (-.1,5) and (-3,5) .. (-1,0);


 \foreach \y in {0,...,39} {
   \draw (outer-\y) -- (inner-\y);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: TikZified version of the above]

Comment: Great! The Tikz-level code makes it much easier. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it's useful.  Incidentally, for the filling then I would work by defining clipping areas rather than try to redraw the individual segments.  It's going to be hard to draw just a segment of the bézier curves, but if you clip against the original curves then you could use the coordinates to define a wedge-shaped segment that you fill with your shading and due to the clipping it will look as though you've just filled the area you want.